# Prove that $\phi$ is class preserving automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\phi:G\to G$ be an automorphism of $G$ such that $\phi|_P=conj(g)|_P$ (restriction of some inner automorphism of $G$) where $P$ is any sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, then is it true that $\phi$ preserves conjugacy classes of $G$?

If the group is nilpotent this is clearly true, but is it true always?

Comment: I think it should be Inn$(P)$ in the first line.

Comment: These automorphisms are usually called Coleman automorphisms and are studied in the context of the normalizer problem of finite groups. To find a counterexample to your statement, we first need groups which have non-inner Coleman automorphisms. These are already not trivially found. Martin Hertwecks counterexample to the normalizer problem and groups with generalized dihedral subgroups have such non-inner Coleman automorphisms... But I can't give you a concrete example. Hope this was helpful in some way.